# OverviewMapControl config

Tags: openlayers

In the map I created in openlayers,
OverviewMapControl is basically useless from zoom levels 0-3 - the red "extent" rectangle just fills the entire OverviewMapControl and can't actually be used to drag the map more then a very minuscule amount. ie. the draggable rectangle would not resize regardless of the zoom level. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/hhudson/addins/InlineXhtml/trunk/examples/example6.htm

Please look this example. The overview map for this would be zoomed in to start with instead of showing the whole map.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Zoom Behavior](http://trac.openlayers.org/wiki/Control/OverviewMap#Customzoombehavior) probably has the information you're looking for; {minRatio: 1, maxRatio: 1} as options to your map constructor might do what you want.

Comment: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/hhudson/addins/InlineXhtml/trunk/examples/example6.htm
Please look this example. The overview map for this would be zoomed in to start with instead of showing the whole map

Comment: Since the URL you gave doesn't appear to have any OverviewMap in it, I'm not sure what you're trying to show.